# Reading and writing a multi-thread shared array

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, task-parallel-library

I have the following code:

```
const int MAX = 101;
const int MIN_COMBINATORIC = 1000000;

int[,] pascalTriangle = new int[MAX, MAX];

Parallel.For(0, MAX, i =>
{
     pascalTriangle[i, 0] = 1;
     pascalTriangle[i, i] = 1;
}); 

int counter = 0;

Parallel.For(0, MAX, x => Parallel.For(1, x, y => 
{
      int value = pascalTriangle[x - 1, y] + pascalTriangle[x - 1, y - 1];
      Interlocked.Exchange(ref pascalTriangle[x, y], value < MIN_COMBINATORIC ? value : MIN_COMBINATORIC);
      if(value > MIN_COMBINATORIC)
          Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
}));

Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", counter);
```

The problem is that it sometimes prints out the correct answer (`Result: 4075`), but sometimes it prints a random (and wrong) answer, such as:

- `Result: 2076`
- `Result: 1771`
- `Result: 0`

I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that I'm reading and writing a shared array between multiple threads.
As you can see, I tried adding `Interlocked.Exhange()` for thread-safe write operations, but I could not find a similar method for reading (There's a `Interlocked.Read()` but it can only read `long` variables)

How can I make the above code run concurrently in a thread-safe manner?

Comment: It could be made thread safe by using some synchronization primitives, but I'm not sure it will work because it seems to rely on previous calculations which may not be complete when running in parallel.

Answer (score 3):

The value variable in

```
int value = pascalTriangle[x - 1, y] + pascalTriangle[x - 1, y - 1];
```

is dependent on two items in the array. Due to concurrency, those values can change between adding those two items, storing them into `value`, and passing that value into `Interlocked.Exchange`. This means that by the time you store `value` in `pascalTriangle[x, y]`, the values in `pascalTriangle[x - 1, y]` and/or `pascalTriangle[x - 1, y - 1]` could have changed.

I actually can't think of an easy concurrent solution for this. The obvious solution is to not do this concurrently. If this the actual code you want to use, there is no real benefit to running this concurrently since it is only looping 101 * 101 = 10,201 times, which can be done very quickly (the first parallel code to initialize the triangle is only looping 101 times, so that can be single-threaded too). If you are creating multiple triangles like this, then you might benefit from concurrently creating triangles (in other words, this method that creates a triangle is single-threaded, but the caller calls this method multiple times on separate threads).

If you really want a concurrent solution, you will need to figure out how to implement a locking mechanism that can lock the 3 array items you are accessing, and (the difficult part) lock them in such a way that deadlocking cannot occur. And even if you come up with a solution, the overhead of all of the locks might actually make the code slower than doing it non-concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using a [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) in the `Systems.Collections.Concurrent` namespace.

If BlockingCollection doesn't fit your needs this namespace has a bunch of different types of collections that are all thread-safe like a dictionary, stack, queue, etc.

Comment: This seems interesting! How would I map my two dimensional array to a one dimension `BlockingCollection`?

Comment: The best way would probably be to have an array of `BlockingCollections`

Comment: How would you reformulate the first `For` loop where I'm creating the pascal triangle? I need to set specific indexes, and a collection is sequential

Comment: Furthermore, it seems that taking an element from `BlockingCollection<T>` actually removes it from the collection, is there some way to just fetch an object and leave it there?